# TightVNC and SSH

Tags: ssh, vnc, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

Lets assume this [state (imageshack image)](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/6525/networku.png) of network. I want to SSH-tunnel connection between VNC clients and VNC servers.

[image]

Both PC1 and PC2 runs TightVNC server and SSH server and have allowed ports 22.
PC client want to connect to PC1 using [TightVNC Java viewer](http://www.tightvnc.com/release-jviewer-2.6.php). What addresses need to be entered into TightVNC Java viewer (Remote Host? Port? SSH Server?) What configuration need to be made to router to forward to right PC? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to set up port forwarding on your router. Let's play this through using ssh as example (every other protocol would work the same).

If you had only one machine you could simply forward port `22`. Since you can forward a port only to one machine this is not an option in your case. Make up two port number for your machines. In this case I will use `10022` and `20022`. Now you have to set up two forwardings on your router:

- One from external port `10022` to internal ip & port `10.0.0.12:22`
- One from external port `20022` to internal ip & port `10.0.0.14:22`

This means that every external request on port `10022` goes to port `22` (ssh) of your PC1.

From your external PC you now need two ssh connections to IP `88.65.41.128`. Note that those connections can't work on default port `22` but on `10022` and `20033`.

The same can be done with every other protocol/service. Just replace the port `22` with the port of that service.

Alternatively you can tunnel every service through ssh. I don't know the tighVNC port but let's assume it's `9000`. You can set up the tunnel to PC1 with:

```
ssh -L 9001:localhost:9000 user@88.65.41.128:10022
```

This connects to PC1 via ssh and forwards the adress `localhost:9000` (from the view of PC1) to the port 9001 of the machine you execute this on. I choose 9001 so that you could forward tightVNC from PC2 at the same time:

```
ssh -L 9002:localhost:9000 user@88.65.41.128:20022
```

Now you can connect tightVNC from your remote machine using the addresses `localhost:9001` and `localhost:9002`.